# Locale in Browser concerning date-input

Tags: javascript, date, locale

I have a custom date-input in a web-application (not mine, I am just maintaining it). This date-input works perfectly fine in the browser that I use (Chrome with german language). This date-input does not work however on a client's machine, who has a canadian chrome installed.

Now I tried setting my language in chrome to canadian english in order to reproduce the bug, but to no avail: The date-input still works fine for me in my browser even if I switch to canadian english.

Now my question is: how can I setup my chrome browser to behave like it was installed on a machine with a canadian windows?

I have no source-code to show, it is just three input fields that take day, month and year. Some Javascript-Logic combines these three inputs into a Javascript Date-Object. This mechanism works fine on german browser but fails on canadian english.

The main question therefore is: Why can't I reproduce the error, even if I switch my browser to Canadian English? (In the meantime I have also switched my Windows-Settings to Canadian English, but not luck in reproducing the error)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it:**

It's the timezones. I had to change the systems timezone to a Canadian timezone. After that I could reproduce the bug like described by the client.

The root cause is that there are several Javascript Methods (like getDate) that depend on the local timezone of the browser. If you want to steer clear of local timezones, use the corresponding UTC-Methods instead (like getUTCDate)

Here is a nice article on the whole matter:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-date-and-time-in-javascript

(scroll down to "Date Methods with UTC")